# regex - Making all letters in a text lowercase using re.sub in python but exclude specific string?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a script to convert all uppercase letters in a text to lower case using regex, but excluding specific strings/characters such as "TEA", "CHI", "I", "@Begin", "@Language", "ENG", "@Participants", "@Media", "@Transcriber", "@Activities", "SBR", "@Comment" and so on.

The script I have is currently shown below. However, it does not provide the desired outputs. For instance when I input "@Activities:   SBR", the output given is "@Activities@activities:  sbr@activities: sbrSBR". The intended output is "@Activities": "SBR".

I am using Python 3.5.2

Can anyone help to provide some guidance? Thank you.

```
import os
from itertools import chain
import re

def lowercase_exclude_specific_string(line):
    line = line.strip()
    PATTERN = r'[^TEA|CHI|I|@Begin|@Language|ENG|@Participants|@Media|@Transcriber|@Activities|SBR|@Comment]'
    filtered_line = re.sub(PATTERN, line.lower(), line)
    return filtered_line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's see why you're getting the wrong output.

> For instance when I input "@Activities: SBR", the output given is
>   "@Activities@activities: sbr@activities: sbrSBR".

This is because your code

```
PATTERN = r'[^TEA|CHI|I|@Begin|@Language|ENG|@Participants|@Media|@Transcriber|@Activities|SBR|@Comment]'
filtered_line = re.sub(PATTERN, line.lower(), line)
```

is doing negated character class matching, meaning it will match all ***characters*** that are ***not*** in the list and replace them with `line.lower()` (which is "@activities: sbr"). You can see the matched characters in this [regex demo](https://regexr.com/3oped).

The code will match ":" and " " (whitespace) and replace both with "@activities: sbr", giving you the result "@Activities`@activities: sbr@activities: sbr`SBR".

Now to fix that code.  Unfortunately, there is no direct way to negate ***words*** in a line and apply substitution on the ***other words*** on that same line. Instead, you can [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) the line first into individual words, then apply `re.sub` on it using your `PATTERN`. Also, instead of a negated character class, you should use a [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions):

> (?!...)
>       Negative lookahead assertion. This is the opposite of the positive assertion; it succeeds if the contained expression *doesn’t* match at
>   the current position in the string.

Here's the code I got:

```
def lowercase_exclude_specific_string(line):
    line = line.strip()
    words = re.split("\s+", line)
    result = []
    for word in words:
        PATTERN = r"^(?!TEA|CHI|I|@Begin|@Language|ENG|@Participants|@Media|@Transcriber|@Activities|SBR|@Comment).*$"
        lword = re.sub(PATTERN, word.lower(), word)
        result.append(lword)
    return " ".join(result)
```

The `re.sub` will only match words *not* in the `PATTERN`, and replace it with its lowercase value. If the word is part of the excluded pattern, it will be unmatched and `re.sub` [returns it unchanged](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Each word is then stored in a list, then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)ed later to form the line back.

Samples:

```
print(lowercase_exclude_specific_string("@Activities: SBR"))
print(lowercase_exclude_specific_string("@Activities: SOME OTHER TEXT SBR"))
print(lowercase_exclude_specific_string("Begin ABCDEF @Media @Comment XXXX"))
print(lowercase_exclude_specific_string("@Begin AT THE BEGINNING."))
print(lowercase_exclude_specific_string("PLACE @Begin AT THE MIDDLE."))
print(lowercase_exclude_specific_string("I HOPe thIS heLPS."))

@Activities: SBR
@Activities: some other text SBR
begin abcdef @Media @Comment xxxx
@Begin at the beginning.
place @Begin at the middle.
I hope this helps.
```

**EDIT**:
As mentioned in the comments, apparently there is a tab in between `:` and the next character. Since the code splits the string using `\s`, the tab can't be *preserved*, but it can be *restored* by replacing `:` with `:\t` in the final result.

```
return " ".join(result).replace(":", ":\t")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation! I would like to clarify concepts I am unfamiliar with. For "Negative lookahead assertion", does it mean that if the expression in the pattern does not match the words in the text, the script will continue searching the text for the matching expressions? Does "\s+" refer to whitespaces? Does ".*$" mean that the expressions have to be exactly matched?

Comment: Hi, I have tried the script. There are some words that are not excluded. These are "@Begin" which is on the first line of the text and is converted to "@begin". "*TEA" and "*CHI" are also not excluded and they have been lower cased. How do I exclude "*TEA" and "*CHI"? When I added them to the pattern, the script does not work. Does the asterisk interfere with the pattern? The other issue is that the script does not preserve the tab spacing between "@Activities:" and "SBR" and all the expressions with a colon in between them. How could I preserve the tab spacing in the lines of the text?

Comment: The **[negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions)** means that the pattern matching fails if the word is part of the pattern. So, the substitution is not performed. Note that my code does the matching _per word_.`\s+` refers to 1 or more whitespaces. `.*` means any character any number of times. `$` means up to the end of the string. You can read about it in any regex reference, like this **[Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)** for Python.

Comment: "_"*TEA" and "*CHI" are also not excluded and they have been lower cased._": In your question, you specified "TEA" and "CHI" **without** asterisks, so that's what I did. (Changing the question after the answer isn't accepted well here in SO). But yes, you have to add them to the pattern to exclude them: `\*TEA` and `\*CHI` (you have to escape `*` because it's a regex special character).

Comment: "_These are "@Begin" which is on the first line of the text and is converted to "@begin"._": Hmm. I don't know how you tried it, because it works when I tested it. "@Begin" is excluded and is not converted to lowercase. I updated my answer to include that test case.

Comment: "_The other issue is that the script does not preserve the tab spacing between "@Activities:" and "SBR" and all the expressions with a colon in between them._" : OK, for this, I did not know that ":" is separated from the next character by a tab. It is again not obvious from your question. My answer splits the string based on whitespaces (`\s`), which includes tabs. It can't _preserve_ tabs exactly, but it can be _restored_ by doing a string replace or another re.sub. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience in replying my issues! For the "@begin" problem, I now resolve it using the ".replace("@begin", "@Begin")" by appending it at the back of "return " ".join(result)".

Comment: There is one more issue I wish to clarify, i.e. the "I" inside the pattern is a pronoun and is not the first letter of words. I replace "I" inside the pattern with "\bI\b". Is this the correct way? I checked the output text and it seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes, using `\bI\b` will explicitly specify the letter "I" by itself. It seems to be working with that.